# Spring Boot Hibernate @ManyToMany assiciation without @JoinTable

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to create Many-to-Many association without defining a join table?

I have an Oracle database from which I need to query events (table Event) and their targets (table Target). Event can have multiple targets, and a target can have multiple events.

Event table consists of columns such as (Id, Name, Info...). However, Target table only consists of columns (EventId and TargetName). So it is using the same Id as Event-tables PK.

Do I need to create a join table to my database, or can this be programmed somehow in Java?

Comment: The ideal would be to create a table that relates them, everything else .. they are sloppy.

If both tables share the ID and that is why it is related to them, it is really a OneToOne relationship since the PK cannot be repeated. To model an entity that refers to a table, the entity must have a PK.

Comment: @JLazar0 I think this is actually a one-to-many, since I get multiple results from Target table with an id, but only a single row from Event, when using the same ID

Comment: For me it is also oneToMany, which does not mean that you do not need a JoinTable, if not annotate the entity with JoinColumn in the property that joins the tables